# Display dates in input text boxes before form is POSTed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this form that posts to a PHP script by selecting a date range, here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpkp0o0w/) for visual understanding. How can I show the dates in empty boxes/input fields (no input allowed) depending on the radio-button selected BEFORE it gets POSTed?

thanks in advance!

Example:

```
 I select one month ago:
(  )       (  )     (X)     (  )
1day     1week     1month    3months

-----------------
|2014 - 11 - 01  |   Date From: (the date being selected)
-----------------

-----------------
|2014 - 12 - 01  |  Date: To: (the present day, today)


 ---------
| get aht |  (button)
 ---------
```

here is my form:

```
<div id="menu_option">
        <h1>Menu Option</h1>
            <div id="button_position">


        <div id="date_selector">    
            <label>Select Date Range</label>
            <form action="show_aht2.php" method="post" id="formtopost">
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1d" checked="checked"/>1d
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1w" />1w
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1m" />1m
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="3m" />3m
                    <input type="button" id="aht_btn" name="get_aht" value="Get AHT" />
            </form>
  </div><!--date selector-->

                <div class="clear"></div>   

  <button id="refresh_page">Refresh Page</button>

    </div>
```

CSS: I'd like to show the date boxes before the AHT button. Also, How can I make all buttons the same size?

```
/*container for all divs inside*/
#container {
width:1450px;   
}

/*map size*/
#map_size{
width:1190px;
height:1300px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position: relative;
float:left;
}

/*menu bar option*/
#menu_option{
width:230px;
height:600px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position: relative;
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
}

input[type="radio"] {
margin-left:10px;
}

#date_selector{
border:3px;
border-color:black;
}

#button_position{
/*width: 100px;
height: 80px
position: absolute;*/
}

#button_position button{
font-weigth:bold;    
font-size:1.3em;
}

button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}

button {
margin:5px auto; 
font:16px tahoma; /*every size you want.*/
}

/*clear */
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: "in a box" in the sense?

Comment: yes syntax error lol

Comment: So u can use a div before that button to show it. is it ok?

Comment: well as long that it fits in the "menu option" CSS that you see in my fiddle, yes

Comment: Do you want to display the dates before button click using Javascript or after form post using PHP?

Comment: @Sithu I want to show them before the form is POSTed. I want it to be dynamic, so meaning the dates keep changing if radio buttons keep changing before POST. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the date range live before the form is POSTed and you want the dates to be POSTed, you would need to add two `readonly` text boxes in the form and use the javascript code below.

#### HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="from_date" name="from_date" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" id="to_date" name="to_date" readonly="readonly" />
```

#### Javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatDate(d) {
      var dd = d.getDate()
      if ( dd < 10 ) dd = '0' + dd;

      var mm = d.getMonth()+1
      if ( mm < 10 ) mm = '0' + mm;

      var yy = d.getFullYear();
      if ( yy < 10 ) yy = '0' + yy;

      return yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    }

    function getDateRange(value){
        var now = new Date(),
            y = now.getFullYear(),
            m = now.getMonth(),
            d = now.getDay();

        var diff = {};
        diff['1d'] = 1;
        diff['1w'] = 7;
        diff['1m'] = 30;
        diff['3m'] = 90;
        var from_date = new Date(y, m, d - diff[value]);

        $('#from_date').val(formatDate(from_date));
        $('#to_date').val(formatDate(now));
    }

    $(function(){
        $("input[name=date_selected]").click(function(){
            getDateRange($(this).val());       
        });
        getDateRange($("input[name=date_selected]:checked").val());
    });
</script>
```

Here is [the working code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzdxwr9n/1/).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! thanks a lot I appreciate your help! I just modified a few things to fit my code! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" id="formtopost">
    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1" checked="checked"/>1d
    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="7" />1w
    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="30" />1m
    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="90" />3m
    <input type="button" id="aht_btn" name="get_aht" value="Get AHT" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
    if($_POST && $_POST['date_selected']){
        $today = new datetime();
        $date_selected = new datetime('-'.$_POST['date_selected'].' days');

        echo '-----------------<br />';
        echo '| '.$today->format('Y-m-d').' |<br />';
        echo '-----------------<br />';
        echo '| '.$date_selected->format('Y-m-d').' |';
        echo '-----------------<br />';

    }
?>
```

Comment: it tells me **Undefined index: date_selected** on line **if($_POST['date_selected']){**

Comment: Yeah i dont do check before use this index, just send form one time

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/jpkp0o0w/2/

```
    $("#aht_btn").click(function () {
    var someDate = new Date();


var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
    var valSelected = $("[name=date_selected]:checked").val();
    if(valSelected == "1d")
    {
       someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() - 1); 
    }

    if(valSelected == "1w")
    {
        someDate.setMonth( someDate.getDate() - 7);

    }

    if(valSelected == "1m")
    {
        someDate.setMonth( someDate.getMonth() - 1 );

    }

    if(valSelected == "3m")
    {
        someDate.setMonth( someDate.getMonth() - 3 );

    }

    var dd = someDate.getDate();
    var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = someDate.getFullYear();
    $("#datefrom").text(y + "-" + mm + "-" + dd);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Simply change the event : http://jsfiddle.net/jpkp0o0w/7/

```
$("[name=date_selected]").click(function () {
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for the dates to be displayed before the form is POSTed, not after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to achieve this is using JavaScript to update the value in the input elements upon change of the radio buton value. To avoid any changes on the input boxes give them the attribute `disabled="disabled"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateDate(newval) {
    document.getElementById('IDdateFrom').value = newval;
</scirpt>
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1d" onchange="updateDate('DATE1d')"  checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1w" onchange="updateDate('DATE1w')"/>
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1m" onchange="updateDate('DATE1m')"/>
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="3m" onchange="updateDate('DATE3m')"/>

<imput type="text" name="IDdateFrom" id="IDdateFrom" value="DATE1d" disabled="diabled">
```

Comment: The code here is not complete. It just shows the tools you can use to achieve your goal. You need to fill the places with DATEXX with the corresponding values when generating the form in php.